# Extract single json object from rows with column values as json key and value

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following table with my attempt at extracting what I would like:

```
with pv as (
    select 2 as user_id,'StaffDashboard' as panel_class, 'wip_fields_rg' as widget_reference, 'hours' as widget_value
    union all select 2,'StaffDashboard','display_rg','calendar'
    union all select 2,'MatterHome','option_rg','afe'
)
select json_agg(obj)
from pv,
json_build_object(pv.panel_class, json_build_object(pv.widget_reference,pv.widget_value)) obj
where pv.user_id = 2;
```

This returns the following:

```
[{"StaffDashboard" : {"wip_fields_rg" : "hours"}}, {"StaffDashboard" : {"display_rg" : "calendar"}}, {"MatterHome" : {"option_rg" : "afe"}}]
```

user_id, panel_class and widget_reference provide a unique key. json_agg is obviously the wrong method.  What I would like is the following:

```
{
 "StaffDashboard" : {"wip_fields_rg" : "hours","display_rg" : "calendar"}, 
 "MatterHome" : {"option_rg" : "afe"}
}
```

i.e. widget_reference and widget_value 'grouped' by panel_class.  The intention is to return the json to the browser to provide user preferences for certain widgets.  Any ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
with pv as (
    select 2 as user_id,'StaffDashboard' as panel_class, 'wip_fields_rg' as widget_reference, 'hours' as widget_value
    union all select 2,'StaffDashboard','display_rg','calendar'
    union all select 2,'MatterHome','option_rg','afe'
), panel as(
select pv.panel_class, json_object_agg(pv.widget_reference,pv.widget_value) as content
from pv
where pv.user_id = 2
group by pv.panel_class
)
select json_object_agg(panel_class, content)
  from panel
```